# Android 4.2.2 not compatible

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am getting emails from Android 4.2.2 users of my application saying that Play Store displays a message that my app is not compatible any more with their devices.
This is how I have manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure the problem is the android version and not the screen width of devices or a custom rom with changed dpis?

Comment: How can I know that? I am not good at all this stuff. Sorry.

Comment: Show the complete manifest, you may to declare wich screens your application is compatible with `<support-screen>` tag and also specify what Android has the user that says is not available and if this user has the system unmodified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mainly for tablets. I found this thanks to the answers above:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#hardware-requirements

I was using mainly

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
```

And I had to changed to:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

because many tablet don't have telephony